# Deleting subdata in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a document structure like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5087b582da50fc570073e094"),
    "grade" : "A",
    "distance" : "470",
    "items" : [
        {
            "history" : [                   
                ...
            ],
            "same" : [
                {
                    "split" : " 1.48",
                    "time" : " 28.56",
                },
                {
                    "split" : " 4.48",
                    "time" : " 28.56",
                },
                ...
            ],
            "name" : "Bill"
        },
        {
            "history" : [                   
                ...
            ],
            "same" : [
                {
                    "split" : " 2.48",
                    "time" : " 28.26",
                },
                {
                    "split" : " 4.49",
                    "time" : " 28.57",
                },
                ...
            ],
            "name" : "Joe"
        },
        {
            ...

        }

    ]
}
```

I want to delete any items from the `same` array where the split value is < 4.
This should delete the first entry in the `same` array from Bill and Joe.
This is just an example document and there are many that are the same.

In my head, this is what I need to do:

1. Loop through all documents,
2. Check if any `split` values of the `same` arrays are <4
3. Remove these (maybe using `update` and `$pull`?)

Can anyone help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I would suggest you store your split and time as numbers, and not as strings as it's not good to do comparisons with that.

With the current data structure, this is something you will have to script in program with whatever language you prefer. Assuming that this is a one-off thing you need to do, what you write is fine. I don't think it's going to be possible to do this with atomic updates to the document, so instead, you will have to do all the data wrangling in your script/program.

If this is a very common task to do, as opposed to just a one time thing, then I would 
suggest you restructure your data into the following:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5087b582da50fc570073e094"),
    "grade" : "A",
    "distance" : "470",
    "history" : [
        ...
    ],
    "same" : [
        {
            "split" : " 1.48",
            "time" : " 28.56",
        },
        {
            "split" : " 4.48",
            "time" : " 28.56",
        },
        ...
    ],
    "name" : "Bill"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5087b582da50fc570073e095"),
    "grade" : "A",
    "distance" : "470",
    "history" : [
        ...
    ],
    "same" : [
        {
            "split" : " 2.48",
            "time" : " 28.26",
        },
        {
            "split" : " 4.49",
            "time" : " 28.57",
        },
        ...
    ],
    "name" : "Joe"
},
```

That way, you can remove all of those time very easily with a pull after finding each element (code in PHP):

```
$m = new Mongo();
$c = $m->dbname->collectionname;

foreach ( $c->find() as $r )
{
    foreach ( $r['same'] as $times )
    {
        if ($times['split'] < 4 )
        {
            $c->update(
                array( '_id' => $r['_id'] ),
                array( '$pull' => array( 'same' => $times ) ),
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much - seems like thats exactly what i want